# Java BLE returning no services

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an Android application that uses BLE to communicate to a MCU, currently I am able to make connection to the MCU using my application but when I attempt to discover and get services for the device I am returned a null array and am unsure as to why.

```
//Code used to connect to the device
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState){
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i("TAG", "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i("TAG", "Attempting to start service discovery:" + mGatt.discoverServices());
            services = mGatt.getServices();
            System.out.println("Service 1 is : " + services.get(0));
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i("TAG", "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }
```

The output:

> 09-26 16:33:09.648 10917-10931/bamboomobile.medhead I/TAG: Connected to GATT server.
>
> 09-26 16:33:09.648 10917-10931/bamboomobile.medhead D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: DC:1B:A3:10:B9:D5
>
> 09-26 16:33:09.658 10917-10931/bamboomobile.medhead I/TAG: Attempting to start service discovery:true
>
> 09-26 16:33:09.668 10917-10931/bamboomobile.medhead W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
>                                                                        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                            at bamboomobile.medhead.MainMenu$1.onConnectionStateChange(MainMenu.java:86)
>                                                                            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:186)
>                                                                            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
>                                                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
>
> 09-26 16:33:09.688 10917-10931/bamboomobile.medhead D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=DC:1B:A3:10:B9:D5 Status=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once connected, you need to call `mGatt.discoverServices()`. Then in the `onServicesDiscovered` callback you can use `mGatt.getServices()` and proceed.